# What is the Ask Ubuntu Clean Up script?

Tags: scripts

how and where is the script installed?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Ask Ubuntu Clean Up
// @namespace     http://userscripts.org/users/217436
// @include     http://cleanup.thepcspy.com/*
// @include     http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include     http://www.askubuntu.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = "(" + function() {
    if (window.location.hostname.indexOf("cleanup.thepcspy.com") != -1)
        return $('#barbanner').hide();

    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cleanup.thepcspy.com/media/external.css" type="text/css" />');
    $('#custom-header').after('<div id="aucuholder" class="container"></div>');

    $.getJSON('http://cleanup.thepcspy.com/?callback=?', function(data){
        $('#aucuholder').html(data);
        $('#aucuopen').click(function(){$('#aucuqs').toggle();return false;})
    });
}.toString() + ")();";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) script.  You can install it from here:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Once the extension is installed, clicking on the "Install UserScript" link on the Clean Up site should prompt you to install it.